# Layout params in multiline (android)

Tags: java, android, layout

is possible to configure eclipse for generate the layout parameters with each param in a different line? That is:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

rather than

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:orientation="vertical">
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, I hated this myself and went preference hunting :-)

Eclipse > Window > Preferences > XML > XML Files > Editor

It's the 'Split multiple attributes each on a new line' that you want

[image: Preferences]

Now when you want to format it, CTRL+A (select all) then CTRL+SHIFT+F (this will format your XML)